# Is there an equivalent phrase to "a priori" and "a posteriori" to indicate "during"?

Tags: latin

If *a priori* means "ahead of time" and *a posteriori* means "after the fact", is there a latin phrase to denote "during the course of the fact"?

*A periori*, perhaps?  Or am I just making things up?

Comment: [*In flagrante*](https://www.lexico.com/definition/in_flagrante_delicto)?

Comment: The question is based on wrong assumptions about the meaning of these terms. What the question roughly articulates is the origin of these terms. In the present-day English they have, however, acquired rather different meanings, which can be readily found in most dictionaries, including general-purpose ones. The epistemological concepts expressed by these terms are such that there cannot be a third one between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Latin, *a priori* means *from the former* and *a posteriori* means *from what follows*. In English, the former is often used to describe reasoning from cause to effect ([OED](https://oed.com/view/Entry/9943)), and the latter used to describe reasoning from effect to cause ([OED](https://oed.com/view/Entry/9424)). They're opposites; there isn't a third Latin-derived phrase that slots neatly in between the two.

Yet there is a Latin phrase, occasionally used in English, for the present time: *hic et nunc*, literally *here and now* ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hic%20et%20nunc)). It is usually used to refer to the present moment while looking erudite. Here are a few examples I found through [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/):

> However farfetched the notion might appear at first, I realized in the end that, *hic et nunc*, Christ was not irrelevant to the problems that interest Professor Parker (Avery Dulles, "Ignatius Among Us," *America*, 2/4/2013.)

> The yearning is for the *hic et nunc* of a close embrace of life, the celebration of some vast nuptials that might help him conjure away the time by which he has lived. (Victor Brombert, "Max Frisch: The Courage of Failure," *Raritan*, Fall 1993.)

> A place shall be considered " artistic " whenever a critic has chosen to define it in a positive way, making of it a desired and desirable alternative to the French *hic et nunc*. (Stamos Metzidakis, "The Utopian Vision of French Criticism," *Symposium*, Fall 1990.)